# Steps to install 32 bit wine on 64 bit 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, wine, 64-bit, software-installation, 32-bit

Any help on this matter would be appreciated.

I have 64 bit 12.04 LTS installed, I am looking for everything needed, step by step order to install 32 bit wine in order to run windows 32 bit software and drivers to connect to USB devices in order to download stored collected data.

Since the end of free support for windows XP is approaching I am jumping to Linux in order to continue using perfectly good hardware.  The drivers can not be upgraded to work with current windows versions, the company has long been out of business.  Why be forced to stop using perfectly good operating hardware when an OS is no longer supported.

I am trying to do this with the currently installed 64 bit 12.04 LTS without having to uninstall the 64 bit and install the 32 bit version or should I just ditch the 64 bit and start over with the 32 version of ubuntu?

I have some experience with linux but am no expert by any means.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: have you read this http://askubuntu.com/questions/74690/how-to-install-32-bit-wine-on-64-bit-ubuntu?rq=1 ?

Answer (score 1):

I Was having the same problem. I just upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit and was trying to get Office 2007 to work. It won't run in a 64-bit wine configuration. After al ot of searching, this is what I came across:

- The folder in which all your wine software are installed is known as your WINEPREFIX. By default this folder resides in your home (~) directory by the name '.wine'. There can be more than one WINEPREFIX.
- There also exists an environment variable known as WINEARCH which represents the mode of your current wine settings, i.e. 64-bit or 32-bit.
- THIS IS IMPORTANT. At the time of the creation of a WINEPREFIX the value of WINEARCH decides the mode in which wine will function when running applications from that WINEPREFIX.

By default the WINEARCH variable is set to the value 'win64' (stands for 64-bit) on a 64-bit Ubuntu installation therefore the automatically created WINEPREFIX has a 64-bit operation mode. In order to change this mode we need to 1) delete the current WINEPREFIX. 2) set WINEARCH to 'win32' 3)Create a new WINEPREFIX. The Steps:

#### NOTE: These steps are to be done after installing wine. You can easily do that using the Ubuntu Software Center. search for Wine 1.6 and click install.

1. Open up the terminal by pressing Ctrl + Alt + T. And type the following commands:

   ```
   cd ~
   rm -rf .wine
   rm -f .config/menus/applications-merged/wine*
   rm -rf .local/share/applications/wine
   rm -f .local/share/desktop-directories/wine*
   rm -f .local/share/icons/????_*.xpm
   ```
2. Now to set your environment variable and also to create your new 32-bit `WINEPREFIX` go ahead and type:

   ```
   WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine winecfg
   ```

That's about it I guess! This worked for me! now all you need to do is to install your 32-bit applications.