# How to install .net framework 3.5 on wine?

Tags: software-installation, wine, winetricks

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I want to use Multicharts,a windows application using wine. Multicharts requires .net framework 3.5. Is it possible to install. I have 64 bit OS.
I found code below on different question.

winetricks dotnet30

There appearers to be a problem with OS being 64 bit.

Comment: I think you need to make a new 32-bit Wine configuration. This helped me: http://askubuntu.com/questions/74690/how-to-install-32-bit-wine-on-64-bit-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Use version 35.

```
winetricks dotnet35
```