# Microsoft Office 2010 (Wine)

Tags: wine

I have Wine installed.
I installed a MS Office 2010 Professional Plus (.iso) file.

I opened it with Disk Image Mounter, and it generated a folder for me. I went into Wine and typed the directory name etc. and  then `/setup.exe` since that was what the setup file was called.

In the middle of installation Wine says that it has encountered errors and the installation has failed.

This is the part of Terminal that seems like it contained the errors - it's sort of my error log, since I ran MS Office setup through Terminal.

Here goes:

```
err:msi:ITERATE_WriteRegistryValues Could not create key L"SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\CTF\\TIP\\{70FAF614-E0B1-11D3-8F5C-00C04F9CF4AC}\\Category\\Category\\{70FAF615-E0B1-11D3-8F5C-00C04F9CF4AC}\\{A8BA876D-E619-11D3-8F5D-00C04F9CF4A0}"
err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"WriteRegistryValues" returned 1627
err:msi:ITERATE_WriteRegistryValues Could not create key L"SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\CTF\\TIP\\{70FAF614-E0B1-11D3-8F5C-00C04F9CF4AC}\\Category\\Category\\{70FAF615-E0B1-11D3-8F5C-00C04F9CF4AC}\\{A8BA876D-E619-11D3-8F5D-00C04F9CF4A0}"
fixme:service:SERV_QueryServiceObjectSecurity 0x1029f68 4 (nil) 0 0x18be570 - semi-stub
fixme:service:SERV_QueryServiceObjectSecurity 0x1029f68 4 0x1029e68 28 0x18be574 - semi-stub
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationInitialize (0x18bdee4, 0x18bdfc0, 1024, 0x0): stub
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationFree (0x18bdee4): stub
err:rpc:I_RpcGetBuffer no binding
err:rpc:I_RpcGetBuffer no binding
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationInitialize (0x15ace64, 0x15acf40, 1024, 0x0): stub
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationFree (0x15ace64): stub
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationInitialize (0x15ace94, 0x15acf70, 1024, 0x0): stub
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationFree (0x15ace94): stub
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationInitialize (0x15ace54, 0x15acf30, 1024, 0x0): stub
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationInitialize (0x15ace34, 0x15acf10, 1024, 0x0): stub
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationInitialize (0x15ace14, 0x15acef0, 1024, 0x0): stub
fixme:rpc:handle_bind_error unexpected status value 1765
err:rpc:RpcAssoc_BindConnection rejected bind for reason 0
t create key L"SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\CTF\\TIP\\{70FAF614-E0B1-11D3-8F5C-00C04F9CF4AC}\\Category\\Category\\{70FAF615-E0B1-11D3-8F5C-00C04F9CF4AC}\\{A8BA876D-E619-11D3-8F5D-00C04F9CF4A0}"
err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"WriteRegistryValues" returned 1627
err:msi:ITERATE_WriteRegistryValues Could not create key L"SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\CTF\\TIP\\{70FAF614-E0B1-11D3-8F5C-00C04F9CF4AC}\\Category\\Category\\{70FAF615-E0B1-11D3-8F5C-00C04F9CF4AC}\\{A8BA876D-E619-11D3-8F5D-00C04F9CF4A0}"
fixme:service:SERV_QueryServiceObjectSecurity 0x1029f68 4 (nil) 0 0x18be570 - semi-stub
```

Comment: Try whit this beta script:  https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-2665-Microsoft_Office_2013.html

Comment: 2010 will only install in 32bit, you need to create a 32bit prefix and install to that path

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that the installer could not write a registry key.

I found [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/a/74716/590483) how to switch wine to 32 bit. I used probably 64 bit on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

That worked fine for me...

Oh, year, and I set up the windows version to Windows 7.