# How to install .net framework 4.5 on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: wine, 64-bit, 16.10

I have tried the `WINEARCH=win32 winecfg` command but it was giving me this `wine: invalid directory prefix32 in WINEPREFIX: not an absolute path
Aborted`.  My question is why does this not work on Ubuntu 16.10 but [Free Gaza's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74690/how-to-install-32-bit-wine-on-64-bit-ubuntu) solution to the same question works?