# Can't run appliciation with Wine. Can someone familar with Wine, tell me the problem?

Tags: command-line, windows, wine

So I'm trying to run Discord Bot Maker which is a web application. This is what I get in terminal when I do the command: `wine "Discord Bot Maker.exe"`.

```
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:system:SetProcessDPIAware stub!
wine: Unhandled page fault on read access to 0x00000004 at address 0x440c49 (thread 0009), starting debugger...
```

Also, it opens Wine with a button saying save log. This is what it looks like:

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x00000004 in 32-bit code (0x00440c49).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:00440c49 ESP:0032fbb8 EBP:0032fbe4 EFLAGS:00010246(  R- --  I  Z- -P- )
 EAX:00000000 EBX:00000000 ECX:00000000 EDX:0032fbdc
 ESI:00000000 EDI:7b478da0
Stack dump:
0x0032fbb8:  00000003 00000000 7b478da0 00753090
0x0032fbc8:  007530a4 007530a4 004042f1 00000000
0x0032fbd8:  00000000 00000000 00000014 0032fbfc
0x0032fbe8:  00440bbc 00000064 00000000 00000064
0x0032fbf8:  00000064 0032fc1c 00440273 0032fc48
0x0032fc08:  00752358 00751ca0 7b410000 00000001
Backtrace:
=>0 0x00440c49 in discord bot maker (+0x40c49) (0x0032fbe4)
  1 0x00440bbc in discord bot maker (+0x40bbb) (0x0032fbfc)
  2 0x00440273 in discord bot maker (+0x40272) (0x0032fc1c)
  3 0x0040662e in discord bot maker (+0x662d) (0x0032fc30)
  4 0x0040496e in discord bot maker (+0x496d) (0x0032fcac)
  5 0x004041ec in discord bot maker (+0x41eb) (0x0032fde4)
  6 0x00458768 in discord bot maker (+0x58767) (0x0032fe30)
  7 0x7b4605fc call_process_entry+0xb() in kernel32 (0x0032fe48)
  8 0x7b461644 in kernel32 (+0x51643) (0x0032fe88)
  9 0x7bc8090c call_thread_func_wrapper+0xb() in ntdll (0x0032fea8)
  10 0x7bc838dd call_thread_func+0xfc() in ntdll (0x0032ffa8)
  11 0x7bc808ea RtlRaiseException+0x21() in ntdll (0x0032ffc8)
  12 0x7bc52913 call_dll_entry_point+0x3d2() in ntdll (0x0032ffe8)
  13 0xf7610b7d wine_call_on_stack+0x1c() in libwine.so.1 (0x00000000)
  14 0xf7610ce0 wine_switch_to_stack+0x1f() in libwine.so.1 (0xffe2bfd8)
  15 0x7bc5891e LdrInitializeThunk+0x24d() in ntdll (0xffe2c028)
  16 0x7b46777a __wine_kernel_init+0xa69() in kernel32 (0xffe2d198)
  17 0x7bc597f3 __wine_process_init+0x152() in ntdll (0xffe2d208)
  18 0xf760ed37 wine_init+0x2c6() in libwine.so.1 (0xffe2d268)
  19 0x7c000ac2 main+0x81() in <wine-loader> (0xffe2d6b8)
  20 0xf7431637 __libc_start_main+0xf6() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
0x00440c49: cmpw    0x4(%ecx),%ax
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (67 modules)
PE    400000-  52e000   Export          discord bot maker
PE   1c20000- 1c91000   Deferred        nw_elf
ELF 7b400000-7b7e0000   Dwarf           kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b410000-7b7e0000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bc00000-7bcf6000   Dwarf           ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bcf6000   \               ntdll
ELF 7c000000-7c004000   Dwarf           <wine-loader>
ELF 7e073000-7e097000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7e080000-7e097000   \               imm32
ELF 7e107000-7e131000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7e131000-7e17a000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7e17a000-7e1a5000   Deferred        libpng12.so.0
ELF 7e1a5000-7e1c0000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7e1c0000-7e270000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
PE  7e28b000-7e29f000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-localization-obs
PE  7e290000-7e29f000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-localization-obsC:\windows\system32\api-ms-win-core-localization-obsolete-l1-2-0.dll
ELF 7e29f000-7e2b3000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-1<
PE  7e2a0000-7e2b3000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-1
ELF 7e2b3000-7e2c7000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0<el
PE  7e2c0000-7e2c7000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0
PE  7e2c7000-7e2dc000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-
PE  7e2d0000-7e2dc000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-C:\windows\system32\api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-1.dll
ELF 7e2dc000-7e2f0000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-fibers-l1-1-1<el
PE  7e2e0000-7e2f0000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-fibers-l1-1-1
ELF 7e2f0000-7e313000   Deferred        libtinfo.so.5
ELF 7e313000-7e339000   Deferred        libncurses.so.5
ELF 7e340000-7e354000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0<elf
PE  7e350000-7e354000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0
ELF 7e354000-7e487000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  7e370000-7e487000   \               oleaut32
ELF 7e487000-7e4a4000   Deferred        jsproxy<elf>
  \-PE  7e490000-7e4a4000   \               jsproxy
ELF 7e4a4000-7e4e0000   Deferred        winhttp<elf>
  \-PE  7e4b0000-7e4e0000   \               winhttp
ELF 7e4e0000-7e50b000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE  7e4f0000-7e50b000   \               msacm32
ELF 7e50b000-7e58b000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7e520000-7e58b000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7e58b000-7e6c4000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7e5a0000-7e6c4000   \               ole32
ELF 7e6c4000-7e77c000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE  7e6d0000-7e77c000   \               winmm
ELF 7e77c000-7e796000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7e780000-7e796000   \               version
ELF 7e796000-7e8c6000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e7a0000-7e8c6000   \               gdi32
ELF 7e8c6000-7ea1b000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  7e8e0000-7ea1b000   \               user32
ELF 7ea1b000-7ea92000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7ea30000-7ea92000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7ea92000-7ecd4000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7eaa0000-7ecd4000   \               shell32
ELF 7ecd4000-7ed4b000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7ece0000-7ed4b000   \               advapi32
ELF 7ef4b000-7ef5e000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ef5e000-7ef6b000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7ef6b000-7ef86000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7ef86000-7ef90000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF 7ef90000-7efe5000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efec000-7f000000   Deferred        psapi<elf>
  \-PE  7eff0000-7f000000   \               psapi
ELF f7414000-f7419000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f7419000-f75cf000   Dwarf           libc.so.6
ELF f75d0000-f75ed000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF f7608000-f77bf000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f77c1000-f77e6000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF f77e8000-f77e9000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
00000008 (D) Z:\home\user\DBM\discord bot maker.exe
    00000009    0 <==
0000000e services.exe
    00000020    0
    0000001f    0
    00000014    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000012 winedevice.exe
    0000001c    0
    00000019    0
    00000018    0
    00000013    0
0000001d plugplay.exe
    00000022    0
    00000021    0
    0000001e    0
00000023 explorer.exe
    00000028    0
    00000027    0
    00000026    0
    00000025    0
    00000024    0
System information:
    Wine build: wine-2.0.2
    Platform: i386 (WOW64)
    Version: Windows XP
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 4.10.0-33-generic
```

Comment: Did you find your application listed  in the Wine App Database?  https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&sTitle=Browse%20Applications&sOrderBy=appName&bAscending=true

Comment: @ubfan1 It isn't there. The program is quite small, probably only 100 downloads and I'm probably the first one to attempt this so I think it's just down to installing required stuff first but since I'm not familar with wine, I don't know what.

Answer (score 1):

on that image , i catch the bit of Operating System

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x00000004 in 32-bit 
code (0x00440c49).
```

and than we catch

```
Wine build: wine-2.0.2
Platform: i386 (WOW64)
Version: Windows XP
```

on image up , we got the WOW64 , i think that must be install the wine on OS 64 bit . However, you install the wine on OS 32 bit .

if you're starting a new prefix (ie on a new install of Ubuntu), you'll need to do a few special things:

```
# Move the old prefix (if one exists)  
# You could rm -rf it if you don't want it.    
mv ~/.wine/ ~/oldwine/    

# Create prefix with rightarch, per
# http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#32_bit_wineprefix   
WINEARCH=win32 winecfg
```

And that's it. Unless you're specifying another prefix that doesn't exist yet, you shouldn't need to set WINEARCH again.

And ultimately, as Wine64 matures, this should be something that's less and less relevant. Wine64 should be able to run 32bit applications.

my reference : [How to install 32 Bit Wine on 64 Bit Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74690/how-to-install-32-bit-wine-on-64-bit-ubuntu)

Comment: I've got 32 bit laptop, so it isn't 64 bit Ubuntu.

Comment: Did that, but on the 2nd command I got a lot of errors. https://pastebin.com/spFJgWnJ